# detach specific package in R if loaded

Tags: r, package, detach

I'm facing some `plyr` vs. `dplyr` problems in my code, so **I would like to detach the `plyr` packge in case it has been loaded before.**

This is how far I got,

```
ifelse(sum(grepl("package:plyr",search()))==0,
       "plyr not loaded",
       detach("package:plyr"))
```

but this code throws an

```
Error in ifelse(sum(grepl("package:plyr", search())) == 0, 
"plyr not    loaded",  : 
substitution has length 0 
Additional warning:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Comment: this happens because `detach` returns a NULL (eg, `ifelse(0, 1, NULL)`), otherwise using ifelse would be fine: `ifelse(sum(grepl("package:plyr",search()))==0, "plyr not loaded", {detach("package:plyr"); invisible(0)})` would work for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
if(any(grepl("package:plyr", search()))) detach("package:plyr") else message("plyr not loaded")
## plyr not loaded
library("plyr")
## if(any(grepl("package:plyr", search()))) detach("package:plyr") else message("plyr not loaded")
```

Generally you want to use `if` and `else` for program control and `ifelse()` only for vectorized logical operations, like data recoding.